# make all views in activity clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, onclicklistener

Trying to make all views in my activity clickable, I do `implements OnClickListener` in the activity signature and in the XML of each view I have `android:clickable="true"`. But clicking on a view does not seem to work? Here is my listener:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.text_1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "ok ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up,  your activity implements a OnClickListener, but you will need to find all your views and setOnClickListener to them programatticaly.  Instead try another approach using the xml attribute `android:onclick`:

1. Rename the `onClick(View v)` to `myClickAll(View v)` in your activity,
2. Remove the `@Override` from this method and the `implements OnClickListener` from the class
3. whichever view you want to have this click listener add another attribute and value of  `android:onclick="myClickAll"` to each tag (where you also have `android:clickable="true"`)

Then you should be good to go.

Comment: That's a good idea. I usually reserve it to distinguish between views. I imagine there has to be a more global way than adding that line in xml. But if no one else comes up with anything, I'll do it this way.

Comment: Dont forget to use styles.xml if you find yourself writing a lot of the same attribute tags. More info here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `setOnClickListener();`

```
    TextView text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    text_1.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView text_2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    text_2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: ah. That's what I left out. Thanks. +1